# Proof of dividing fractions $\frac{a/b}{c/d}=\frac{ad}{bc}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions

For dividing two fractional expressions, how does the division sign turns into multiplication? Is there a step by step proof which proves

$$\frac{a}{b} \div \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{d}{c}=\frac{ad}{bc}?$$

Answer (score 9):

Write $\frac{a}{b} \div \frac{c}{d}$ as
$$
\frac{\ \frac{a}{b}\ }{\frac{c}{d}}.
$$
Suppose you wanted to clear the denominator of this compound fraction. You could try multiplication by $\frac{d}{c}$, but you'll have to multiply the top and the bottom of the fraction to avoid changing it. So, you end up with
$$
\frac{\ \frac{a}{b}\ }{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{\ \frac{a}{b}\ }{\frac{c}{d}} \cdot \frac{\ \frac{d}{c}\ }{\frac{d}{c}} = \frac{\ \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{d}{c}\ }{\frac{c}{d} \cdot \frac{d}{c}} = \frac{\ \frac{ad}{bc}\ }{1} = \frac{ad}{bc}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

There is something assumed about the order of operations in the notation 
$a/b \div c/d$.  I see this as a problem in pedagogy when fractions are first introduced in schools.  Somehow we have to *assume* that the slash bars are to be done before the division symbol, even though each of those symbols stands for "divide".  If I were you, I'd always stay in the habit of writing fractions as $\frac{a}{b}$ rather than $a/b$.

end rant.

Traditionally, $\frac{a}{b} \div \frac{c}{d}$ means:  Beginning with the quantity $\frac{a}{b}$, divide this by the quantity $\frac{c}{d}$.  So let's think of a small example not dealing with fractions first:

$$ 8 \div 2.$$

Now, we all know the answer is $4$.  But I want to draw your attention to the fact that this expression is the same as:

$$ 8 \cdot \frac{1}{2}.$$

What happened?  Well division by $2$ is the same as multiplication by $\frac{1}{2}$, because $\frac{1}{2}$ is the *multiplicative inverse*, or *reciprocal* of $2$.  By defintion, the reciprocal of a number $x$ is a number $y$ such that $x\cdot y = 1$.
Every nonzero number has a reciprocal.  If $x \neq 0$, then its reciprocal is $\frac{1}{x}$ (because $x \cdot \frac{1}{x} = 1$).  So, for $x \neq 0$:

$$ 8 \div x = 8 \cdot \frac{1}{x}.$$

Now, if $x$ is a fraction, such as $\frac{c}{d}$, then the most natural way to write the reciprocal of $x$ is by "flipping" the fraction.  The reciprocal of $\frac{c}{d}$ is $\frac{d}{c}$ (well... because $\frac{c}{d}\cdot \frac{d}{c} = \frac{cd}{cd} = 1$).  Thus:

$$ 8 \div \frac{c}{d} = 8 \cdot \frac{d}{c}. $$

Finally, it does not matter so much what the first factor of the expression is.  It could be another fraction:

$$ \frac{a}{b} \div \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{d}{c} = \frac{ad}{bc}.$$

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

The fraction  $x = \frac{a}{b}$ is the solution to $b \cdot x = a$. Similarly $y = \frac{c}{d}$ solves $d \cdot y = c$. Now, multiply the left-hand-side with $b \cdot x$ and the right hand-size with $a$ which preserves the equality since $a = b \cdot x$. We get

$$
 \begin{eqnarray}
    (b \cdot x) \cdot ( d \cdot y) &=& c \cdot a \\
    (b \cdot d) \cdot (x \cdot y) & = & (c \cdot a)
 \end{eqnarray}
$$
Thus $ ( x \cdot y) $ is the fraction $\frac{a \cdot c}{b \cdot d}$.

Answer (score 2):

Division is normally the inverse operation to multiplication, so - as I have explained to one of my daughters this week - dividing by $n$ is the same as multiplying by $1/n$. In one sense this is a totally trivial observation, but in another it involves a much deeper understanding of what is going on.

It follows that *division*, where it makes sense, can be replaced by *multiplication by the reciprocal* (or inverse), which is the precise case my daughter wanted to understand. Getting hold of this opens up a world of algebraic possibilities, so it is well worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ x/z\ =\ y\ \iff\ x\ =\ y\ z\:.\ $ Thus $\rm\ \dfrac{a}b\!\!\ \bigg/\!\! \dfrac{c}d\ =\ \dfrac{a}b\!\!\dfrac{d}c\ \iff\ \dfrac{a}{b}\ =\ \dfrac{a}b\!\!\dfrac{d}c\!\!\dfrac{c}{d} $

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ are fractions.  That is, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are whole numbers and $b\ne0$, $d\ne0$.  In addition we require $c\ne0$.

Let $\frac{a}{b}\div\frac{c}{d}=A$.  Then by definition of division of fractions , $A$ is a unique fraction so that $A\times\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}$.

However, $(\frac{a}{b}\times\frac{d}{c})\times\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}\times(\frac{d}{c}\times\frac{c}{d})=\frac{a}{b}\times(\frac{dc}{cd})=\frac{a}{b}\times(\frac{dc}{dc})=\frac{a}{b}$.

Then by uniqueness (of $A$), $A=\frac{a}{b}\times\frac{d}{c}$.