# Division by Multiplication of Reciprocal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm trying to prove the following:

$${ad\over bc} = {\frac ab \over \frac cd} $$

First, $${\frac ab} = ab^{-1} $$ and $${\frac cd} = cd^{-1} $$
So the compound fraction above equals $$ (ab^{-1})({cd^{-1}})^{-1} $$

Here's where I get stuck. How do I handle the second term? I know $$(ab)^{-1} = (a^{-1})(b^{-1})$$ but what how is a number such as $$(b^{-1})^{-1}$$ simplified? I know it equals b, but how do I reach that conclusion from defining division as the multiplication of reciprocals?

Comment: $\dfrac cd = cd^{-1}$, $$\;\dfrac{1}{\frac cd} = (cd^{-1})^{-1}$$

Comment: $(b^{-1})^{-1}=b^{-1\times -1}=b$

Comment: Nice fundamental stuff. Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71157/proof-of-dividing-fractional-expressions/71186#71186 (dealing with the same expression as this, but you took it a lot farther so you deserve a very different answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a useful fact: for any number $x$ (a member of a field)
and any integers $m$ and $n$ (which may each be positive or negative),

$$ (x^m)^n = x^{mn}.$$

From this you can conclude

$$ (b^{-1})^{-1} = b^{(-1)(-1)} = b^1 = b. $$

Of course then you have to have first established $(x^m)^n = x^{mn},$
including the cases where one or both of $m$ and/or $n$ is negative,
so that you can make use of that identity.
But it is such a useful identity that it is well worth proving.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing this informally; it's not unreasonable at all to take $(x^{-1})^{-1} = x$ as axiomatic.

---

Here's a common little trick with inverses to show they are *unique*: if we posit that $xy = 1$ and $yz = 1$, then we can calculate:

$$ x = x1 = xyz = 1z = z $$

A more convenient fact that can be proven from this is

> If $ax = 1$ has a solution for $x$, then that solution is *unique*

so to prove that $c = a^{-1}$, all you need to do is to show that $ac = 1$.