# Dividing fractions

Tags: arithmetic

When dividing fractions, you can find the quotient by multiplying them with the second fraction reciprocated.  e.g. 5/6 divided by 7/8 = 5/6 times 8/7.  Why does this work?

Comment: This thread should give you the answer. 


http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71157/proof-of-dividing-fractional-expressions

Comment: This question, IMHO, begs for an intuitive answer [e.g. groups, group size, area model etc.], whereas the alleged question "that has been asked before" only gives very technical explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Because:

If a : x = b, then what is y such that a . y = b ?

I mean express y in terms of x and you will see why it works.