# Reciprocal of a product with reciprocal: $(c \cdot d^{-1})^{-1}$ is equal to $c^{-1} \cdot d$

Tags: real-numbers

(My question *is* similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71157/proof-of-dividing-fractional-expressions) at a high level, but I am looking for something more rigorous.)

I have started into Michael Spivak's "Calculus" textbook.  Problem 3 (v) on page 14 asks for a proof that "$\frac{a}{b} \big/\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad}{bc}$, if b, c, d $\neq 0$".

The only proof that I can come up with assumes that $(c \cdot d^{-1})^{-1}$ is equal to $c^{-1} \cdot d$, which is true, but I can't prove it.

At this point in the chapter, Spivak has listed these nine basic properties of numbers:

1. $a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$
2. $a + 0 = 0 + a = a$
3. $a + (-a) = (-a) + a = 0$
4. $a + b = b + a$
5. $a \cdot (b \cdot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot c$
6. $a \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot a = a$; $1 \neq 0$
7. $a \cdot a^{-1} = a^{-1} \cdot a = 1$, for $a \neq 0$
8. $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$
9. $a \cdot (b + c) = a \cdot b + a \cdot c$

This is actually one of the questions with an answer in the back of the book, where Spivak makes the same assumption I do.  So here's my question: How do we know that $(c \cdot d^{-1})^{-1}$ is equal to $c^{-1} \cdot d$ given these properties?

Comment: Whatever $(c \cdot d^{-1})^{-1}$ is, when we multiply it with $c \cdot d^{-1}$, we should get $1$. So if you multiply $c^{-1} \cdot d$ with $c \cdot d^{-1}$ and get $1$...

Comment: Multiply $(c \cdot d^{-1})^{-1}$ by $c^{-1} \cdot d$. If you get $1$, then either one is the inverse of the other.

Comment: @Normal Human: The axiom of choice???

Comment: @AsafKaragila Autocomplete fail, I was thinking "axioms" (since the question is based on axiomatic treatment of real numbers). There is no "analysis" here, btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint. First, show that the multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}$ (are any field in general) is unique.

Then, show that both $(c\cdot d^{-1})^{-1}$ and $c^{-1}\cdot d$ are multiplicative inverses of $d^{-1}\cdot c$.

Comment: I know what a field is, but I'm afraid that I don't know what "$\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}$" means.  I should warn you too that I've been out of school for a decade, and I didn't get a math degree.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ is just a way of saying "the real numbers, not including 0". So he's saying any (nonzero) real number has a unique inverse.