# Confusion regarding proof of subtraction of a negative number.

Tags: arithmetic, education

In the following proofs I have read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/852022) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2305900), it appears to me, both assume what is being proven is already true and use it in the proof itself.

What I understand so far:

1) Subtraction can be defined as addition such that

$ a - b = a + (-b) $

2) From this definition

$a - (-b) = a + - (-b)$

3) Using the definition of the additive inverse, then for any number *c*, *-c* satisfies the equation

$c + (-c) = 0$

4) $x = - (-b)$ is the number that solves the equation $(-b) + x = 0$, meaning $-(-b) = b$ for it to be true.

Step 4 is where my confusion occurs. $x = - (-b)$ still, but couldn't it have been assumed that

$-(-b) = -b$ and instead the equation $b + x = 0$ would be true?

Point being that in the proof(s) it's already assumed that $-(-b) = b$, and that knowledge is used to construct an equation that is tailored to prove that fact. But if the assumption were $-(-b) = -b$, then the equation can be rewritten to prove that as well.

Can someone please clear my confusion with detailed and explicit steps? I would be very grateful as this has been occupying my thoughts for the last few days.

Comment: Don't you think that since $(a+b)-b=a$ is true whenever $b>0$, then we should arrange it so that it's true when $b<0$ too?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry, I don't see what you're driving at. I'm wondering why in step 4 the equation couldn't be written as $b + x = 0$. If it were then $x = -(-b) = -b$ would satisfy the equation and therefore would make $-(-b) =-b$ true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is being assumed beyond the definition of additive inverse. We can prove that $-(-b) = b$ -- i.e., that $b$ is an additive inverse of an additive inverse of $b$ -- from the definition of additive inverse.

The fact that $-b$ is an additive inverse of $b$ means, by definition,
$$ b + (-b) = 0$$
An additive inverse of $-b$ is whatever number $x$ satisfies 
$$ x + (-b) = 0$$
But comparing this to the first equation, which we know to be true, we see that $x = b$ satisfies this second equation. Thus $b$ is an additive inverse of $-b$, i.e., $b = -(-b)$.

Note: Unfortunately the symbol $-$ is being used in two distinct ways, to denote an additive inverse and to denote subtraction. This is standard, so I didn't want to change it, but that may be part of what is confusing here.

Comment: Careful. depending on which axioms you are building on you can not (in general) say that $b$ is the additive inverse. It is  a  additive inverse. That doesn't invalidate the actual statement, it is one of these traps one can fall into.
Some axioms are set up in such a way that it just requires inverse and unit and one then proves they are uniquely determined, while other sets assume the uniqueness of solving an equation and deduce the rest.

Comment: @H.Gutsche I'll edit my answer. But if additive inverse isn't unique, can we define subtraction?

Comment: You can always define it but the question is would it be a well defined definition (pun intended). From the question I take it we are dealing with an abelian group (here some numbers), and within the abelian group as it is defined the unit and the inverse elements are unique. That is a quality of the group. But you can define subtraction for natural numbers (there is no negatives, and they are not a group) and here one needs a uniqueness statement. That only comes because it is not clearly specified what "numbers" are. Don't worry to much about it.

Answer (score 0):

We are not assuming$$ -(-b)=b$$

We prove it is $ b.$

We can not prove that$ -(-b)=-b.$

Try it and see what happens.